# Additional License or Additional Licenses

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

In my webpage, I have to get input from user to purchase addition license. Here my doubt is the lable should be Additional Licenses or Additional License.

Ex: Additional License ($10 /license) < INPUTBOX >

Thanks.

Comment: Licence could be used as "countable" and "uncountable". If it costs $10 for ONE license, you should use a singular form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input field is for the number of additional licenses, the label should say **"Additional licenses ($10 per license):"**.

"Software license" is countable, so a user could purchase additional **licenses** (plural). See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) for many examples:

> A **software license** is a legal instrument... governing the use or redistribution of software.
>
> The hallmark of proprietary **software licenses** is that the software publisher grants the use of one or more copies of software... but ownership of those copies remains with the software publisher.

Here's an example [from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814175):

> How to obtain **additional licenses** for Windows XP

Comment: In the English of England the noun *licence* is properly spelled with a *c*, and it is a countable noun. Only the verb *to license* is spelled with an *s*.

Comment: Good point, @WS2. I stuck with the US spelling since this seems to be the OP's choice.